# Kinda newish to Ubuntu, and I need some internet help

Tags: networking, internet

I've Ubuntu on a dual boot, and I primarily use Windows. I was having an issue where my machine would completely crash when I tried to log in with the GUI. So I figured that I could get an update from the command line to fix it, which fixed the crashing issue.

However, most of the way through this long update process, it started displaying lots of error messages before finishing up. I didn't know what any of them meant (and unfortunately don't have any images), but it finished up, and fixed that other issue, but now it fails to connect to any network, wired or not.

Viewing the network settings in the GUI, I see something like there's no network hardware detected or something like that. I would look now but I'm booted into Windows on the affected machine.

Edit:
I saw a comment asking for my machine and version so I'll add those now:
I'm on an HP Envy dv7 laptop, I believe a 2012 model though I've had trouble finding a serial number or anything (got it refurb before I knew anything at all whatsoever about computers) and it's running Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted with Windows 10.

Edit 2:
sudo lshw -class network returned hardware specifications (addresses, manufacturers, etc.)
arp -a returned nothing

Comment: Hi There! This community if full of surprisingly talented **Ubuntu** fanatics. To get the best out of it, you might need to [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/758877/edit) your question in-detail as to what version of Ubuntu that you're using, what's your PC model, Network hardware... etc. This will ideally attract us to help and support you more given the fact that you have addressed the issue. Right now, even I'm clueless. :)

Answer (score 0):

While a lot of times GUI would just work for most people, sometimes you will need to use the terminal (the black window where you can type commands) to fix problems. In general, no network can be because of several things.

1. Do you have the proper driver installed. Run the following command and see if anything is returned.

   ```
   sudo lshw -class network
   ```
2. Can the driver correct auto configure ethernet interface. Try run the following and see if you see your router address.

   ```
   arp -a
   ```
3. Do you have the correct network layer settings. Try the following and see if your computer has an IP address.

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```
4. Do you have the correct routing settings. Try the following and see if you have the correct routing table.

   ```
   route -n
   ```
5. Do you have the correct DNS settings. Try the following and see if your DNS can resolve to a well known website.

   ```
   nslookup www.google.com
   ```

If any item doesn't have the correct settings, the remaining items will probably not work either.

Ref:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: Okay, I'm not exactly sure what a lot of this means, so I'll type what comes up after I try each of these if I don't understand it.

Comment: Try to update your question with the output, as it might help others offer solutions.

Comment: 1. returned hardware specifications (addresses, manufacturers, etc.)
2. arp -a returned nothing
3. Didn't list an IP address.
4. 'Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway    Genmask    Flags Metricc Ref    Use Iface'
5. Returned nothing (I'm not even connected to a network right now so, no surprises there)

 I think Ubuntu is having other interface issues as well, as I experienced "tearing" while moving windows across the screen, like when a game is outputting frames at a different rate than your monitor refresh rate.

Comment: Looks like it failed at step 2. I haven't dealt with something like this before so best to wait for some others to answer. It is best for you to update your question with output of 1 and mention 2 didn't return anything.